# ASP.Net MVC 4 - Shoud I create a custom membership provider (Intranet, no Database, no sso)

Tags: com, asp.net-mvc-4, membership, intranet

In an intranet ASP.NET MVC 4 application I have to do authentication with forms authentication. I can't use integrated security for this application because it also have to be reachable by untrusted entities.
There is another limitation: The web application is some kind of interface for a COM backed solution having it's own logon mechanisms (username + password). So I don't have a database.

I would like to make use of built in features as much as possible.
I don't need to implement a process for registering or managing accounts. Basically, I just need LogOn, LogOff and change password.

What would be the best approach for this scenario?

I tend to create an custom membership provider? Is this a good idea?

Regards, Martin

Answer (score 0):

You are right. When you build your own CustomMembershipProvider, you can freely customize it to match your requirements. Especially the authentication itself can be changed to log on and off using your existing solution.